# How to assign a position to an object in an arraylist for future access (server / client socket programming

Tags: java, sockets, arraylist

I am trying to create a chat program that connects multiple clients to one server, and the server needs the ability to distribute messages (utf-8 strings) to certain clients and not others. I am trying to create a list of clients (with a position in the arraylist for each one).

Here the code that I currently have in order to create a list of clients (clients in this case are objects) in an arraylist and to somehow use the position to distinguish between each client (if it is possible to assign a number or position to an object or client somehow, I want to do that).

(the code below is within a class called ChatServer)(it is a prototype, not the correct/best solution, I just am using this as the first rough draft idea I had and will probably change it when I learn how to create a list of clients)

First idea/solution/rough draft (using an arraylist):

```
           ArrayList<Object> ListOfClients = new ArrayList<Object>();                        
           int ClientPositionInList = 0;
           int numberofclients = 0;
           for(int i = 0; i < ListOfClients.size(); i++)
           {
                 socket = serverSocket.accept();
                 ClientPositionInList = i;
                 ListOfClients.add(Client);
                 numberofclients = numberofclients + 1;
           }
           System.out.println("Here is the list of currently connected clients": ListOfClients");
```

Here is the full context with all the code and information about how to run the program (with screenshots) but it is really long to read:

[How to connect multiple clients to one server and distributing messages to specific clients in java socket programming using threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591719/how-to-connect-multiple-clients-to-one-server-and-distributing-messages-to-speci?noredirect=1#comment74234811_43591719)

My question is: How should I go about creating a list of clients that connect to one server on a single port? Is this code the correct way to store multiple clients and their position so I can access them later? (I need the ability to choose certain clients to send messages to, while being able to exclude others and/or remove clients from the list)

Comment: Can't you associate some sort of unique ID to a client and implement some findById method to use for your later search?

Comment: @alainlompo I don't know because I never tried that but how would I assign the "unique ID" to each client? would it be having a variable like ClientUniqueID inside the for loop that gets the "i" variable to record the position in the list?

Comment: You can use java.util.UUID like: `UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID()`

Comment: @alainlompo so in this context it would be       for(int i = 0; i < ListOfClients.size(); i++)
                     {
                      UUID uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID(); 
                      System.out.println("This client's id is": uniqueID);
                      
                      ChatServer Client = new ChatServer();
                      ListOfClients.add(Client);
                      
                     }

Comment: you should rather have the uniqueId as an attribute of your Client class. Have a distinct Client class and instead of `ChatServer client...` something like `Client client = new Client(); client.setUniqueId(uniqueID)...`

Comment: @alainlompo so it would be something like this:  private void setUniqueId(Object uniqueID)
 {
  uniqueID = Math.random();
  
 }
 UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
     ChatClient chatclient = new ChatClient();
     Object uniqueID = null;
     chatclient.setUniqueId(uniqueID);

 for(int i = 0; i < ListOfClients.size(); i++) { UUID uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID(); System.out.println("This client's id is": uniqueID); ChatServer Client = new ChatServer(); ListOfClients.add(Client); }